# Customizando temas para API 9 e 10 do Android

Tags: android, android-styles

Tenho um App que roda a parti da API 9 ate 23 do android, no entanto as cores do texto ficam diferente das cores setadas, o correto seria Toolbar Azul com texto branco. O problema ocorre apenas nas API 9 e 10.

[image: Imagem do App em um dispositivo da API 10]

E o style é o seguinte:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="ThemeAccent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Alguma solução para este problema?

Desde já grato!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu aconselho usar uma Toobar, por que é bem mais prático e fácil.
Nos seus layouts coloque:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toobar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/toobarStyle"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        />
```

No seu style coloque:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>     
</style>
<style name="toobarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

No arquivo color use:

```
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">sua cor</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">sua cor</color>
  <color name="colorAccent">#fff</color>
</resources>
```

No onCreate das suas activitys coloque:

```
    Toolbar toobar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toobar);
```

Comment: Vou fazer algumas alterações no style, e já estou usando a Toolbar. Valeu pelo o empenho! :D